# NativeScript app crashing on iOS 14.2 when using an MDM

Tags: nativescript

App works just fine on iOS 14.1 and below (deployed using MDM). It crashes with iOS 14.2 when deployed using an MDM tool (works fine with normal deployment).

Our MDM provider sent us this link for troubleshooting: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666399

The Xamarin team have a fix, but it is very Xamarin specific. Looking for a NativeScript fix.

Our app is built on

```
nativescript  6.7.8
tns-ios 6.5.3
```

Crashlog:

```
error     11:00:27.580673-0500  cloudd  [Request 0x145166db0] Finishing request with error 0x143e47750
error     11:00:27.597337-0500  cloudd  Couldn't pull url from backing account <private> or context <private>
error     11:00:27.597455-0500  cloudd  Couldn't pull url from backing account <private> or context <private>
error     11:00:27.663547-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - unable to load NSUserDefaults suite
error     11:00:27.689133-0500  dasd     Activity <private> not tracked as being started, ignoring it
error     11:00:28.593288-0500  SpringBoard     Snapshot generation request for bundleID: our.app.id rejected due to the app being denylisted.
error     11:00:28.614079-0500  kernel   System Policy: mobileapp(492) deny(1) dynamic-code-generation MAP_JIT requires the dynamic-codesigning entitlement
error     11:00:28.645842-0500  SpringBoard     Snapshot generation request for bundleID: our.app.id rejected due to the app being denylisted.
error     11:00:28.647825-0500  wifid     __WiFiManagerUpdateFamilyPreferences_block_invoke_2: error loading family members: Error Domain=com.apple.family.error Code=-1004 "(null)"
error     11:00:28.647958-0500  familycircled     No iCloud, no family. You know the rules.
error     11:00:28.876152-0500  kernel   Sandbox: mobileapp(492) deny(2) file-test-existence /private/etc/.mdns_debug
error     11:00:29.286648-0500  runningboardd  RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item <RBProcessMonitorObserver| qos:0 qos:(null) configs:{            }>
error     11:00:29.297266-0500  SpringBoard     Unable to get short BSD proc info for 492: No such process
error     11:00:29.304982-0500  SpringBoard     Unable to get short BSD proc info for 492: No such process
error     11:00:29.326567-0500  SpringBoard     Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
error     11:00:29.337173-0500  familycircled     No iCloud, no family. You know the rules.
error     11:00:29.339870-0500  wifid     __WiFiManagerUpdateFamilyPreferences_block_invoke_2: error loading family members: Error Domain=com.apple.family.error Code=-1004 "(null)"
error     11:00:29.354877-0500  SpringBoard     tried to remove an assertion that was never added: <SBFloatingDockBehaviorAssertion: 0x2813fbf80> {
    pinned = NO;
    animated = YES;
    gesture possible = YES;
    visible progress = 0.000000;
    level = in app;
    reason = in app;
    timestamp = 2020-12-08 16:00:28 +0000;
}
error     11:00:29.361299-0500  SpringBoard     HW kbd: Failed to set keyboard focus pid:0 ((null)) scene:(null)
error     11:00:29.361396-0500  SpringBoard     HW kbd: Failed to set keyboard focus pid:0 ((null)) scene:(null)
error     11:00:29.362488-0500  SpringBoard     Snapshot generation request for bundleID: our.app.id rejected due to the app being denylisted.
error     11:00:29.374109-0500  SpringBoard     Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT.
error     11:00:29.817637-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.817768-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.818027-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.818279-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.818612-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.818805-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.819149-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.819241-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.820290-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.820425-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.820482-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
error     11:00:29.820559-0500  duetexpertd      <private> - Current subscription is in a recursion. StreamId: homeScreen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note this is an officially tracked NativeScript issue: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9079

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

Select Target Runner -> Build Settings -> Strip Style -> change from "All
Symbols" to "Non-Global Symbols"